# Based on physical attributes, what is a better position?

Tags: football

In watching a football game, someone may want to pick out a particular player and watch him or her for most of the game.

They may see that, based on their previous field experience, they are comfortable in any position.

Where does a person with an unusual talent in balance (as in the kinesthetic ability) better belong on the field?

Comment: Do you mean what position do usually universal players play?

Comment: @gdrt Balance as in the kinesthetic ability

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't just get what do the first two paragraphs have to do with your question.

Comment: I don't really have enough substance to provide a good answer here, but my gut feeling is central midfield, in a box to box role. A modern, central midfielder has the opportunity to shoot and score in attacks, and to mark and tackle in defence. They must be fit enough to cover 80 metres of the field continually, and fast enough to participate in counter attacks and help thwart them.

Comment: If you're talking about the attribute of balance specifically, it's required by all players - not just dribblers in attack. Defenders need good balance to tackle, and recover from jumping headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that most talented persons in balance belong to forward roles (strikers, advance midfield, forwards). 
And that's because to dribble and shoot you must have good balancing skills, 
you have to know how to hit the ball in every body stance and have good timing, precision and coordination. 
A good example of what I mean is the bicycle kick (or scissor kick), this to me is the most difficult movement in football.
It combines the ability to volley, shoot directly from cross, sense of position and hit the goal from a difficult position, because tipically the player gives the shoulder to the goal when he does a bicycle kick.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Uyqce8m_Q) is the famous Van Basten goal that will explain my point better.

Or [Zidane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QryFUtRtUiM) score in Champions League final 2002.

These are only two examples of great talent in balance, I could give you 100 link of amazing scores to prove my point.

I have seen this also in my experience as football player (I played until I was 19), the most talented in balance and fast guys were assigned to forward roles.

This is just my opinion, and I am not saying that other roles doesn't require good balance skills, but if you ask about balance and coordination I have to say forward.